# LabelDisplay for fusion charts MScombi3d charts

Tags: javascript, charts, fusioncharts

I need some help in displaying the xaxis labels for a MSCombi3d chart.  I have checked and for 2d charts, there are below two attributes available. which when we set  in the chart, the x axis labels will display in a rotated format.

```
labelDisplay='Rotate' & slantLabels='1'
```

But when I try to use the above for a MScombi3d chart it doesnot work. I have gone through the documentation and could only find this attribute xLabelGap='50'. But it does not rotate/display the x axis labels in a slant.

Can someone please suggest the attribute that needs to be used for MSCombi3d charts to display the x axis labels in a slant.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide us a fiddle link or a code snippet of what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `xLabelGap` is perhaps a deprecated or at least not applicable in FusionCharts Javascript version. Although I found some usage of this attribute [here](http://forum.fusioncharts.com/topic/14867-problem-displaying-lable-in-3d-ms-combi-chart/), but nowhere in the official FusionCharts [docs](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes.html)

I found the attributes `labelDisplay` and `slantLabels` in MSCombi3d charts(JS version) functional since its 3.4.0 version. Might work before that too! :D

Below snippet illustrates the use of these attributes with its latest version. You can visit the download [page](http://www.fusioncharts.com/download/).

```js
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'stackedcolumn3dlinedy',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '550',
    height: '350',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "caption": "Business Results 2005 v 2006",
        "xaxisname": "Month",
        "yaxisname": "Revenue",
        "showvalues": "0",
        "numberprefix": "$",
        "labelDisplay": "rotate",
        "slantLabels": "1",
        "animation": "1"
      },
      "categories": [{
        "category": [{
          "label": "Jan"
        }, {
          "label": "Feb"
        }, {
          "label": "Mar"
        }, {
          "label": "Apr"
        }, {
          "label": "May"
        }, {
          "label": "Jun"
        }, {
          "label": "Jul"
        }, {
          "label": "Aug"
        }, {
          "label": "Sep"
        }, {
          "label": "Oct"
        }, {
          "label": "Nov"
        }, {
          "label": "Dec"
        }]
      }],
      "dataset": [{
        "seriesname": "2006",
        "data": [{
          "value": "27400"
        }, {
          "value": "29800"
        }, {
          "value": "25800"
        }, {
          "value": "26800"
        }, {
          "value": "29600"
        }, {
          "value": "32600"
        }, {
          "value": "31800"
        }, {
          "value": "36700"
        }, {
          "value": "29700"
        }, {
          "value": "31900"
        }, {
          "value": "34800"
        }, {
          "value": "24800"
        }]
      }, {
        "seriesname": "2005",
        "renderas": "Area",
        "data": [{
          "value": "10000"
        }, {
          "value": "11500"
        }, {
          "value": "12500"
        }, {
          "value": "15000"
        }, {
          "value": "11000"
        }, {
          "value": "9800"
        }, {
          "value": "11800"
        }, {
          "value": "19700"
        }, {
          "value": "21700"
        }, {
          "value": "21900"
        }, {
          "value": "22900"
        }, {
          "value": "20800"
        }]
      }, {
        "seriesname": "2004",
        "renderas": "Line",
        "data": [{
          "value": "7000"
        }, {
          "value": "10500"
        }, {
          "value": "9500"
        }, {
          "value": "10000"
        }, {
          "value": "9000"
        }, {
          "value": "8800"
        }, {
          "value": "9800"
        }, {
          "value": "15700"
        }, {
          "value": "16700"
        }, {
          "value": "14900"
        }, {
          "value": "12900"
        }, {
          "value": "8800"
        }]
      }],
      "trendlines": [{
        "line": [{
          "startvalue": "22000",
          "color": "91C728",
          "displayvalue": "Target"
        }]
      }],
      "styles": {
        "definition": [{
          "name": "bgAnim",
          "type": "animation",
          "param": "_xScale",
          "start": "0",
          "duration": "1"
        }],
        "application": [{
          "toobject": "BACKGROUND",
          "styles": "bgAnim"
        }]
      }
    }
  }).render();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<!-- Stacked Column 3D + Line Dual Y axis chart showing quarterly cost analysis for the last year. -->
<div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>
```

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AyanGhatak/5oou4ho7/) link for the avobe implementation.

Get to know more about the supported attributes in MSCombination 3d charts from [here](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes.html?chart=mscombi3d).